# django sitemap root url not showing up

Tags: django, django-models, satchmo

my sitemap.xml file is showing every url of my apps as it should do.
but the main /-url (root-url) of my domain is not in the sitemap.xml because its not an app.
and there are no models for the main-page. but as you can see in sitemap.py (see below) 
one needs a model and an app to return something for creating an entry in the sitemap.
but my main-page has no referenced data in the database, so i don't know what to return.

how should i resolve that problem?
[i tried with flatpages but django-flatpages didn't help me either, because i could not tell the admin-interface to create a page with the url "/", it wanted something like "/about/temp.html/".]

my project-directory is looking similar to this:

```
projectname/app1
           /app2
           /app3
           settings.py
           local_settings.py
           sitemap.py
           etc...
```

### sitemap.py

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from app1.models import ModelX
from app2.models import ModelY

class SitemapApp1(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return ModelX.objects.all()

class SitemapApp2(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return ModelY.objects.all()
```

what i have tried is:
i created an app called main with a models.py in it. And in this model i wanted to do somethings stupid, just to have a model now for the main / url, beeing able to return something.

```
class Main(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
projectname/app1
           /app2
           /app3
           /main
                models.py
                __init__.py
           settings.py
           local_settings.py
           etc.
           sitemap.py
```

### sitemap.py new

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from app1.models import ModelX
from app2.models import ModelY
from main.models import Main

class SitemapApp1(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return ModelX.objects.all()

class SitemapApp2(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return ModelY.objects.all()

class SitemapMain(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Main.objects.all()
```

Sure, restarted the server.
Well it doesn't give me an error when i go to domain.com/sitemap.xml
but i doesn't show up with domain.com-entry in sitemap.xml either.

So i am sure, you have a much better solution to my stupid approach of getting domain.com/ root into sitemap.xml.

Appreciat your help.
Thanks a lot in advance!

sc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try and modify this example I got [from here](http://www.semi-legitimate.com/sls/blog/36-tech-tips/61-complete-django-sitemap):

```
class MainSitemap(Sitemap):

    def items(self):
      return [self]

    location = "/"
    changefreq = "monthly"
    priority = "1"
```